# How to change a object's attribute by using another object's method

Tags: python, class, object, oop

I am trying to understand oop in python and tried making a class of a character. Here it is:

```
class Character:

    def __init__(self,health,power,range,position):
        self.health = health
        self.power = power
        self.range = range
        self.position = position

    def get_health(self):
        return self.health

    def set_health(self,value):
        self.health = self.get_health()
        self.health -= value

    def punch(self,value):
        value -= self.power
        return value
```

And i used it here:

```
from character import Character

char1 = Character(100,25,5,3)
char2 = Character(100,20,3,4)

char2.health = char1.punch(char2.get_health())

print(char2.get_health())
```

I tried making it so that when char1 punches char2 loses health but it doesnt work and i get the output of None for some reason.

Comment: Your code prints "75" when I run it.

Comment: It prints 75 for me also.  This cannot be your real code.

Comment: As others have stated, this does not seem to be the original code you wrote. There seems to be at least some difference since it works fine when running it.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of the keyword range is not optimal, here is a better approach:

```
class Character:

    def __init__(self, health, power, char_range, position):
        self.health = health
        self.power = power
        self.range = char_range
        self.position = position

    def get_health(self):
        return self.health

    def set_health(self, value):
        self.health = value

    def punch(self, target):
        damage = self.power
        target.set_health(target.get_health() - damage)
        return damage

# Example usage
char1 = Character(100, 25, 5, 3)
char2 = Character(100, 20, 3, 4)

char1.punch(char2)
print(char2.get_health())
```

Now, when char1 punches char2, it updates char2's health accordingly, and you can check it using char2.get_health().